# Question on the elementary cell of a rectangular/square lattice in magnetic firld?

Tags: magnetic-fields, solid-state-physics, gauss-law, crystals, lattice-model

In all references on the rectangular/square lattice in the presence of a magnetic field, they mention that you get a periodic structure of the model if and only if the flux per plaquette is a rational multiple of quantum flux i.e. $\frac{\Phi}{\Phi_0}=\frac ab$, and then the elementary cell of the model contains exactly $b$ plaquettes.

Can someone please explain:

- why if the flux ratio is irrational, the model is not periodic?
- assuming that the flux ratio is rational $\frac ab$, then, why the magnetic unit cell contain $b$ plaquetts and does not depend on $a$?